# change web root apache mac OS X

Tags: macos, apache

I cant change my web root in apache, for some reason it points to /Sites/folder1/folder2 instead of it pointing to /Sites.
I configured and change my apache 
`<Directory "/Users/saad/Sites">` and
`DocumentRoot /Users/saad/Sites`
restarted my apachectl and still nothing.

Comment: if you haven't already done so try putting an index.html file in the document root

Comment: this question isn't related to programming and would be better asked over at [su]

Comment: @TomIngram I added the index.html restarted apache, nothing changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went to /etc/apache/users/saad.conf and added the virtual host in this form "www.x.dev" to the top of my virtual hosts list. this temporarily fixed the problem. hope this helps

Comment: Worked for me too. I also tried to edit httpd.conf as mentioned above, didn't work. Then I added virtual host and the same custom DocumentRoot to my /etc/apache/users/aza.conf. Worked like a charm. If anyone could explain why, that would be great.

Answer (score 34):

I just meet this problem, too. I need to change the DocumentRoot and point it to my customised directory, which used for saving image files.

Berkay is right, you need edit a bit on your apache httpd.config file, but besides that, you need to do one more change, otherwise the WebSharing won't be able to turn on again.

1. Open your httpd.config by your favorite editor (Probably need to do this if you haven't change the permission access to this file)

   - sudo chmod 666 httpd.conf
   - Open httpd.config, and start editing.
   - sudo chmod 644 httpd.conf, when it's finished, proceed to step 2 (change it back to original permisson access)
2. Find `DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"`, and change it to `DocumentRoot "/Users/leiwang/Sites"` or any other folders you want to.
3. One important thing is, you need to give the Read/Write permission to the folder you specified.

   - sudo chmod -R 747 foldername

Hope it helps:)

Answer (score 8):

Apache has several files with the same name `httpd.conf`

The "oficial" path is in `/usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf`

Comment: after sucking 12 hours with /Library/WebServer/Documents finally I read this answer. My nightmare is solved now, partially...

Comment: In macOS 13.6.3 (Ventura) I used brew reinstall httpd to upgrade, and modified `DocumentRoot | Directory`  of the `/usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf`, now it works.

Answer (score 7):

there is a documentroot property in the /etc/apache2/httpd.conf on osx.
so we can easily change the path like this;

> DocumentRoot "{YOUR_ROOT_PATH}"

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this problem: Once you change the root of web server to somewhere other than the default (/Library/WebServer/Documents), you need setup virtual host, otherwise, localhost will not work, and you will get:
`403 Forbidden` error
You can refer to this link for details on how to set it up:
http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/set-virtual-hosts-apache-mac-osx-10-10-yosemite/

Also make sure the following line is in the configuration file for the web directory if your Max is running OS X 10.10:
`Require all granted`

For your reference, I just remind you if this ever happens to you.

Comment: I was also getting the 403 Forbidden error. But, I solved it by just looking at the permissions of all the folders in the DocumentRoot path. The permissions were not correct. So, I did a chmod 755 in all the folders as suggested in https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204644980/why-am-i-seeing-a-403-forbidden-error-message. Then it worked!

Comment: For me, the main catch was adding `<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot /Library/WebServer/Documents/
</VirtualHost>` to `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

Answer (score 2):

I came across the similar question as you, the httpd.conf under `/private/etc/apache2/` defines the DocumentRoot as `/Library/Webserver/Documents`. But that directory doesn't work!

Instead,the DocumentRoot which actually works is `/usr/htdocs`! Weird!

Answer (score 1):

In case this helps someone else, it looks like Sierra made a backup file for me at:

/etc/apache2/httpd.conf~previous

I was able to copy my old configuration file into the new one, restarted apache and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Although i had rights for my folder (and tried the chmod solutions also), it couldnt work for me.

What i found to work is to edit the User and group that runs the htppd conf file:

in httpd.conf file, change:

```
User daemon to User yourMacUsername (you can find that from folder info)
Group daemon to Group staff (this is the default)
```

Save and restart apache

Answer (score 0):

If someone get `403 forbidden` error, try to update the `DirectoryIndex` inside the `httpd.config` file as well. In case if you forgotten you have .php file in the folder. My config file was in this path `/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` This solve the issue of my macOs Monterey

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Following are the steps to update your document root in the new mac os ventura in 2023. You just need to update a single file.

1). Open the **httpd.conf** file inside the **/Application/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc** folder and search for the text **DocumentRoot**, you can find something like as shown below.

```
DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs"
<Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs">
```

2). Now update the document root path for both the lines, as shown below.

```
DocumentRoot "/Users/Stephen/Projects/Backend/PHP"
<Directory "/Users/Stephen/Projects/Backend/PHP">
```

3). Now the most important step, search for the text **User daemon**, you will find something like as shown below.

```
User daemon
Group daemon
</IfModule>
```

now change the name **daemon** to the username of your OS.

```
User Stephen
Group daemon
</IfModule>
```

4).Now restart your server using the xampp control panel, that's it.

Incase the phpmyadmin doesn't opens in the browser, then simply empty the temp folder inside **/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp**.
For more details, please follow the video link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cWPSBbwmQFE