# Apache 2.4 Can only Use htdocs as webroot

Tags: osx-yosemite, apache2.4

I set up Apache 2.4 yesterday, and it is working with the `htdocs` folder I set up in my home directory. However, I do not want to use htdocs, I want to use a folder in my `~/Documents/web/<project>` directory. I have tried altering `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` and `/etc/apache2/users/<username>.conf` to no avail. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

*FOR WINDOWS:*

please try to modify `<your-apache-dir>\conf\http.conf`.

1. Open `http.conf` in the above directory
2. Search for `DocumentRoot`

> *#*
>
> *#* DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
>   
>   *#* documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
>   
>   *#* symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
>
> *#*
>   *DocumentRoot* "***c:/Apache24/htdocs***"

3. Modify the above bolded path.
4. Restart your apache.

(*Note: Restarting apache is important. Any changes you made in apache and php, you have to restart the apache.*)

---

*FOR OSX:*

Other than modifying the `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` and `/etc/apache2/users/<username>.conf`,

you need to do one more change, otherwise the WebSharing won't be able to turn on again. (*according to David_Wang*)

1. Open your `httpd.config` (Probably need to do this if you haven't change the permission access to this file)

   - sudo chmod 666 httpd.conf
   - Open `httpd.config`, and start editing.
   - sudo chmod 644 httpd.conf, when it's finished, proceed to step 2 (change it back to original permisson access)
2. Find `DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"`, and change it to `DocumentRoot "/Users/leiwang/Sites"` or any other folders you want to.
3. One important thing is, you need to give the `Read/Write` permission to the folder you specified.

   - sudo chmod -R 747 foldername

(*ref: [change web root apache mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8851544/change-web-root-apache-mac-os-x)*)

Comment: I've done so in the mac equivalent httpd.conf with no effect. Any folder other than htdocs will not serve the site.

Comment: did u restart your apache?

Comment: @spectre-d i have modified the answer, please have a look :)

Comment: I followed it exactly, with same 403 issue that I have been getting. It works fine with `htdocs` but not with any other directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `<Directory>` section (with Requrie all granted) each time you add a new DocumentRoot if it's not within the original document root.